# Create a matrix where each value depends on it's own indices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a n*n matrix with entries `Aij = 5/(i + 2j -1)`.

It's easy enough with a couple of for loops but I just wondered if there was a built in functionality that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple just use meshgrid:

```
 [j i]=meshgrid(1:n);
 A=5./(i+2*j-1);
```

with `n` being the dimension you want.

An even simpler way to do that in your case, where both `i` and `j` go to `n`,  is this one line :

```
A=5./([1:n]'+2*[1:n]-1);
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant solutions +1

Comment: It should be noted that the second solution only works on newer versions of MATLAB possessing [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, even if less elegant and simple of the one proposed by @bla:

```
x=5./(bsxfun(@plus,2:2:n*2,(0:n-1)'))
```

The denominator of the first row is `2:2:n*2`, the other rows are simply the previous row +1.